# For dihedral group, prove $F(R^k)F = (R^{-k})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$R$ is any rotation and $F$ is any reflection.

Comment: What is **your** definition of dihedral group?

Comment: It's a set of all symmetries for a n-gon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so $\;G\;$ is *the* group of all symmetries of a regular $\;n\,-$ gon, and let $\;s\;$ be a(ny, if you will) reflection, $\;t\;$ a rotation in multiples of $\;\frac{2\pi}n\;$ radians.

Now, get convinced that $\;sts=t^{-1}\;$ . Since you seem to be handling a geometric definition, think of this geometrically. A good not os trivial example is with a pentagon, or even a hexagon.

After that, all you need is a little (Very little induction) and some of the group's properties, and observe that $\;s=s^{-1}\;$:

$$t^{-k}=(t^{-1})^k=(sts)^k=stsstssts\cdot\ldots\cdot sts$$

Now observe you have $\;k\;$ pairs of $\;ss=1\;$ together, and deduce

$$(sts)^k=stsstssts\cdot\ldots\cdot sts=st^ks$$

Comment: Thank you so much! But is there any way to prove that $sts=t^-1$ only using the definitions of a group?

Comment: @user3000482 No *unless* you add some characteristics of that group. This is why I asked you what is **your** definition of dihedral group, and based on that I tried to write down a proof.